# Dimension of quotient space and basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces

I'm quickly reviewing the concept of quotient space.

Suppose $V$ is a vector space of dimension $m$ and $W$ is a vector subspace of $V$. Then the quotient vector space is defined as $V/W$, which is a set of equivalence classes, $x ~ y$ iff $x - y \in W$, elements of $V/W$ are the cosets $[x] = x + W$.

I'm trying to find a basis an the dimension of such vector space (which I'm not proving here, but I can easily prove the axioms).

For the basis suppose $x_1, \ldots, x_{m - n}$ is a basis for $W^{\perp}$ and $x_{m - n + 1}, \ldots x_{m}$ is a basis for $W$, then

$$
[\alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots \alpha_{m-n} x_{m-n} + \alpha_{m-n+1} x_{m-n+1} + \ldots + \alpha_m x_m] = \\
\alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots \alpha_{m-n} x_{m-n} + \alpha_{m-n+1} x_{m-n+1} + \ldots + \alpha_m x_m + W = \\
(\alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots \alpha_{m-n} x_{m-n}) + (\alpha_{m-n+1} x_{m-n+1} + \ldots + \alpha_m x_m) + W
$$

we specificaly have $(\alpha_{m-n+1} x_{m-n+1} + \ldots + \alpha_m x_m) + W = W$ hence
$$
[\alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots \alpha_{m-n} x_{m-n} + \alpha_{m-n+1} x_{m-n+1} + \ldots + \alpha_m x_m] =
\alpha_1 [ x_1 ] + \ldots + \alpha_{m-n} [ x_{m-n} ]
$$

Hence we have $\left\{ [x_1],\ldots,[x_{m-n}] \right\}$ are generators for $V/W$, to show linear independence is relatively straightforward and I'll skip it. This proves that $V/W$ is a vector space of dimension $m-n$.

The map

$$
f : [\alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots + \alpha_{m-n} x_{m-n} ] \to (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{m-n})
$$

Is linear isomorphism (or homeomorphism? always confused with the difference) this implies we can identify $V/W$ with $\mathbb{R}^{m-n}$.

Is all of the stated above correct?

Comment: A linear isomorphism satisfies certain explicit properties which a homeomorphism absolutely does not. You can check these definitions yourself on e.g. wiki.

Comment: A "linear isomorphism" is a linear map.  "Homeomorphisms" are not necessarily linear.  The term "linear homeomorphism" is rarely used.

Comment: Note also that homeomorphisms are maps between topological spaces.  If we are only told that $V$ is a vector space, then it could be the case that $V$ does not have a topological structure, in which case it doesn't make sense to talk about a homeomorphism to or from $V$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, please bear in mind my main question is about basis and dimension of $V/W$. But to clarify, just going through wiki, an homomorphism between two algebraic structures (vector spaces in my cases) is a map that preserves the operations of the structure. In my case $f$ preserves the vector spaces operations so it is a homomorphism, right? But it is also an Isomorphism (still definition from wikipedia) since it has inverse which is a homomorphism.

Comment: Therefore each isomorphism is a homorphism (by definition), but not the opposite.