# $R/(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ is regular of dimension $d-r$ if and only if $\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_r\in m/m^2$ are linearly independent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, krull-dimension

> Let $R$ be a regular Noetherian local ring of dimension $d$ with maximal ideal $m\subset R$. For elements $a_1,\dots,a_r\in m$ show that the quotient $R/(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ is regular of dimension $d-r$ if and only if the residue classes $\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_r\in m/m^2$ are linearly independent over $k:=R/m$.

($\Rightarrow$) $R$ is regular implies $\operatorname {dim}_k m/m^2=d$. Assume also that $R/(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ is regular of dimension $d-r$: then $\frac{m}{m^2+( a_1,\dots, a_r)}\cong \frac{m/m^2}{(\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_r)}$ is a $k$-vector space of dimension $d-r$, so the elements $\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_r$ span a subspace in $m/m^2$ of dimension $r$.

($\Leftarrow$) If conversely $\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_r$ span a subspace of dimension $r$, then $\operatorname {dim}_k \frac{m/m^2}{(\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_r)}=d-r$. It is known that if exist elements $a_{r+1},\dots,  a_d\in m$ such that $a_1,\dots,a_d$ generate $m$, then $\operatorname{dim}R/(a_1,\dots ,a_r)=d-r$. So take a basis of the $k$-vector space $m/m^2$, that can be assumed of  the form $\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_r,\bar c_{r+1},\dots \bar c_d$, where $\bar c_{r+1},\dots \bar c_d$ are the residue classes of some $c_{r+1},\dots c_d\in m$ (as every linearly independent subset of a vector space can be extended to a basis). By Nakayama's lemma $a_1,\dots,a_r,c_{r+1},\dots c_d$ generate $m$.

Do you think is correct? It looks quite simple so I suspect that I assumed something that isn't generally true without seeing it, but I checked as well as I could every passage.

Comment: Not proper. The efforts are in [Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)). As the restricted name of the defining article shows questions depend on the contexts. This is abstract math, thereby really fundamental. Steps in need can be found under the section Properties. With the assumptions there no application of [Nakayama's_lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma). The comments on [dimension-of-quotient-space-and-basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3620889/dimension-of-quotient-space-and-basis) give hints.

Comment: @user2432923 sorry I don't understand what mistake are you pointing out; from linear algebra I only used a result on the dimension of the quotient space, that is also on the page you linked, and that a set of independent vectors can always be extended to a basis.